# Multi threading: Why is "End of main" printed before "I am lazy thread"?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, control-flow

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){

    Mythread t  = new Mythread();
    t.start();
    t.interrupt();

    System.out.println("End of main");
 }
}
class Mythread extends Thread {
public void run(){
    try{
    System.out.println("I am lazy thread");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
catch(InterruptedException e){

    System.out.println("I got interrupted");
}
}

}

Output:
End of main
I am lazy thread
I got interrupted
```

Why isn't "I am lazy thread" printed before "End of main" since t.start() is executed before System.out.println("End of main"); inside main()?

Comment: Because starting threads is slower than executing the statements in the main thread.

Comment: Threads feature the method `join` which is essentially "wait until the thread has died". Use that to ensure "End of main" gets printed last.

Comment: Because your main thread has not been preempted by the time it gets to the last statement (`System.out.println()`). Make it do something else before like a very long loop and you shall see preemption and execution of `MyThread` taking over the CPU share. This behaviour is also not guaranteed so in many executions you would see it interleaved differently.

Comment: The two lines have to be printed in _some_ order, because `System.out.println()` is a synchronized method call. But, your program says nothing about the order in which they _should_ be printed. You get whatever you get. If you try it on a different day, or on a different machine, you could, in princple, see the lines printed in the opposite order.

Comment: `start()` means the thread is placed in the queue to processors. It takes a while when it actually start to execute its code, even if there are idle processors. The initial thread continues to execute in a fast pace and prints "I am lazy thread" almost immediately.